# Getting whether Blender is active window using bpy.app.timers

Tags: python, scripting

I am writing a timer script and I want to get whether Blender is the active window.

this an example code for the timer:

```
import bpy
import datetime

counter = 0

def update_time():
    global time
    global now
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    time = bpy.context.scene.timer.time
    bpy.context.scene.timer.time = time + 60
    print(time)
    return 60

def register(): 
    bpy.app.timers.register(update_time)

I have already seen a script which gets whether Blender is the active window like this:

    if event.type == 'WINDOW_DEACTIVATE':
       window_active = False
```

But this runs in a modal operator, so my question is, is it possible to do this with `bpy.app.timers`? I didn't find anything about getting events while in `app.timers`, is it even possible, or do you know a better way?